# jQuery is filtering out html from WordPress content

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working with a highly-modified portfolio plugin based upon this code from Tympanus: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/  Most things are working decently. I've got my custom post type set up, and content is displaying. But my content text is showing up as one big paragraph even though it's been entered as multiple paragraphs. How can I tell the script not to strip the html? For that matter, I would *love* it if it would even display any images entered into the_content area. So far, no luck.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be related jQuery, but whatever service WP is using to supply the content to the call.

I would perform a search on the plugin code, or service that provides the content, looking for `wp_strip_all_tags`.

If you believe the feature is in the JS, search the plugin for `stripHTML` or `.text`.

Comment: My content appears correctly elsewhere on my site. I've searched through the plugin files.  There's only one location in the js file where the .text appears:

`var filterVal = $this.text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
        var count  = numOfItems;
        ulObject.find('li').each( function(i, el) {
            classie.remove( el, 'hidden' );
            classie.remove( el, 'animate' );
            if(!--count){
                setTimeout( function() {
                    doAnimateItems(ulObject.find('li'), filterVal);
                }, 1);
            }
        });`

Comment: How did you make the CPT?  How are you servicing these CPT entries to the script?  Can you confirm the CPT content is getting the text formatting tags?

Comment: I'm sorry: CPT? I'm not familiar with this acronym.  Like I said, I've just modified an existing script to make it work with WordPress. I'm really new to JS and am muddling my way through.  That said, no...the formatting tags are not appearing in the output. I'm sure *something* is stripping the code, but I'm just not sure what, nor how to fix it.  If you take a look at the script linked on the page in my original post, you'll see that it actually handles the data description in a rather odd way by putting all of the data elements into the href element of the main image.

Comment: CPT is Custom Post Type.